# What does Monitor Logging do in Cisco IOS?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, logging

When doing `sh log`, I can see there is a monitor logging configured.

I know that console logging is send to the physical console port, and that buffer logging is sent to the memory of the Switch/Router, and trap logging is sent to a Syslog server. Where is the data going if logging Monitor is configured??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the `terminal monitor` command, that will send debug and system messages to the current terminal session. If you are connected to the device via a VTY line, you need to use this command to see those because it may look like you are connected the the CON line, but you are not.

Cisco maintains extensive documentation that is just a search away:

[Cisco IOS Configuration Fundamentals Command Reference, Release 12.2:](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/ffun_r/frf003.html)

> ## terminal monitor
>
> To display **debug** command output and system error messages for the
>   current terminal and session, use the **terminal monitor** EXEC
>   command.
>
> **terminal monitor**
>
> ### Syntax Description
>
> This command has no arguments or keywords.
>
> ### Defaults
>
> Disabled
>
> ### Command Modes
>
> EXEC
>
> ### Command History
>
> [image]
>
> ### Usage Guidelines
>
> Remember that all terminal parameter-setting commands are set locally
>   and do not remain in effect after a session is ended.
>
> ### Examples
>
> In the following example the system is configured to display **debug**
>   command output and error messages during the current terminal session:
>
> ```
> Router# terminal monitor
> ```

The `logging montor` command will enable terminal line (monitor) logging.

[Cisco IOS Network Management Command Reference](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/netmgmt/command/reference/nm_book/nm_09.html)

> ## logging monitor
>
> To enable system message logging to the terminal lines (monitor
>   connections), use the **logging monitor** command in global
>   configuration mode. To disable logging to terminal lines other than
>   the console line, use the **no** form of this command.
>
> ```
> logging monitor [discriminator discr-name] [severity-level]
>
> no logging monitor
> ```
>
> ### Syntax Description
>
> [image]
>
> ### Command Default
>
> The logging monitor function is disabled.
>
> ### Command Modes
>
> ### Global configuration (config)
>
> Command History
>
> [image]
>
> ### Usage Guidelines
>
> Specifying a severity-level causes messages both at that level and at
>   numerically lower levels to be displayed to the monitor. Table 32
>   shows a list of levels and corresponding syslog definitions.
>
> Table 32 Error Message Logging Priorities and Corresponding Syslog
>
> ### Definitions
>
> [image]
>
> ### Examples
>
> The following example shows how to specify that messages at levels 3
>   (errors), 2 (critical), 1 (alerts), and 0 (emergencies) be logged to
>   monitor connections:
>
> ```
> Router(config)# logging monitor 3
> ```
>
> The following example shows how to use a discriminator named monitor1
>   to filter critical messages, meaning that messages at levels 0, 1, and
>   2 are filtered:
>
> ```
> Router(config)# logging monitor discriminator monitor1 critical
> ```
>
> ### Related Commands
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

> Minimum level of severity required for a log message to be sent to a
>   monitor terminal (not the console).

[Cisco IOS Configuration Fundamentals Command Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/ffun_r/frf013.html)

```
Router# show controllers vip 4 logging

 Syslog logging: enabled
      Console logging: disabled
      Monitor logging: level debugging, 266 messages logged.
      Trap logging: level informational, 266 messages logged.
      Logging to 192.180.2.238
```

[image]

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks, I was hung up on the term terminal monitor and how is showed up in the sh log output as it is slightly different.